# Reversing and resetting rigidbodies?

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation

I want it so that I can make rigidbodies fall then make them go in reverse back to their original places without doing any video editing. So I'll be able to see them fall back into place from different angles. Is there also a way of just animating a rigidbody reset. What I mean by that is so something falls and then X frames later they'll teleport back to where they were so I can do something different with them. Is reversing and resetting during the animation possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to play the animation in reverse, but I think you mean the following (this works for relatively short and simple simulations, else it would take to much time):

- Bake the simulation to keyframes
  [image]
- Open graph editor and make sure every keyframe is selected
  [image]
- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate keyframes and then <kbd>X</kbd> to shift the keyframes horizontally
  [image]
- Click <kbd>Left Mousebutton</kbd> to confirm and then <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd> then <kbd>-</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>, to invert the keyframes
  [image]
- Change the simulation end frames
  [image]

Comment: Thanks it works. Although I think instead of just doing s then -1 you need to do s then x then -1 or you'll just get really weird results